# Issue in loading URL in webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I need to show a login webpage link in webview and the link is something like below

```
url = "https://test-dev.test.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=com.test.td&response=code&value=id test mail&redirect_uri=com.test.ap://oauth2/test";
```

[Modifed the actual URL with different names]

On this page, we have to enter username and password.  Clicking on login will take you to OTP screen, after entering the OTP result will be a url response and from this I need to read the code.  Using this code I have to make a request to get the authentication token for the session.  For token request, response will be Json.

Now I need help in resolving the below:

1. Currently its opening in browser and not in webview.  But other links are opening in webview within the app except the above link.
2. Which is the call back method for handling response from this transaction.

Below is my code:

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(getAuthorizationURL());
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    //  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");    
}


    private String getAuthURL() {
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("test-dev.test.com")
            .appendPath("ta/authorization.oauth2")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "com.test.td")
            .appendQueryParameter("response", "code")
            .appendQueryParameter("value", "id test mail").appendQueryParameter("redirect_uri", "com.test.ap://oauth2/test")

    String url = Uri.decode(builder.build().toString());

    //url = "https://www.google.com/";
    // url = "https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api/about";

    return url;
}


 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url) {

        System.out.println(" shouldOverrideUrlLoading :============ " + Uri.parse(url).getHost() + " url " + url);

        //            if(url.contains("dev.test.com")){
        //                webView.loadUrl(url);
        //                return false;
        //            }
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i uncomment the code inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method also it does not work.

Comment: you are sending intent to browser to handle your url

Comment: Yes, you are opening the browser with the intent. I think you dont need a custom webview anf use the main one, add the url if the url is a correct one else open a browser, but from the activity, not from the webView. Also there are ways to communicate between android and webpages inside webviews, but I think is to extensive to post an answer for that, so I recommend to search for tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you're doing an OpenID authentication.  You're implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` is both firing an intent which will most likely go to the default web browser, and returning `true`.  The return value tells Android whether you're taking control of loading the page (`true`) or leaving it to the web view (`false`).  If you don't take control of handling the URL, the web view will try to load it like a normal page.

You're also immediately directing the web view to your authorization URL in your `onCreate` code.  I'm thinking this is part of the confusion over the navigation behavior you're seeing.

For this kind of authentication process, you don't want to override loading the OTP page.  Let the web view handle that just like anything else.  What you want to do is capture the URL response.  Your `if` statement within `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` should trap the response URL, consume the contents, and respond `true` to let the web view know you've taken care of that URL.  Everything else should be handled by the web view.

Finally, the commented version of the code looks to me like it would send you into an infinite loop, the way you have it written.  You're telling the web view to load the authorization URL, which will lead back to your web client code, which will trap the URL, causing it to load the URL...

Comment: One additional note.  Handling authentication directly in your web view is considered insecure, because your own app could be sniffing the password or otherwise misbehaving (from the user's perspective).  Best practice is to use the system browser to load the authentication page.

Comment: Thank you, now I modified  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)  to return false and to load it in webview.  But i am getting a blank page.  The same URL works fine on iOS.   Any help?

Comment: Solved the blank issue, I had to set the height of the webview to match_parent.

Comment: Great to hear.  If the answer helped, please upvote and/or accept it.  Thanks.